# Creating a CLLocationCoordinate2D using Codable protocol

Tags: swift, mkannotation, codable

I'm trying to conform a custom class to the MKAnnotation protocol. To create this class, I'm decoding from a JSON feed using the Codable protocol.

```
class CustomClass: NSObject, Codable, MKAnnotation {

  var id: String
  var name: String
  var lat: Double?
  var lon: Double?
  var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

  // Note, the coordinate var is not a part of the decoded JSON file. 
  // It is derived from the lat and lon attributes, which are in the
  // JSON file.

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case name
    case lat
    case lon
  }

  required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.id = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
    self.name = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
    self.lat = try values.decodeIfPresent(Double.self, forKey: .lat)
    self.lon = try values.decodeIfPresent(Double.self, forKey: .lon)
    self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.lat!, longitude: self.lon!)
  }    
}
```

When I run this code, I get the following error in the line where I set the self.coordinate var:

> Thread 2: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

It looks like the coordinate variable is getting set before the lat and lon variables are decoded. How can I set the coordinate var using the decoded lat and lon vars inside my init method?

Comment: did you try to debug or print `lat` and `lon`? Do they present in the structure, before you construct `coordinate`?

Comment: Yeah, after setting lat and lon, printing them returns optional values back. E.g., Optional(38.8963), Optional(-77.045)

Comment: If `lat` and `lon` can be `nil` then `coordinate` must be optional, too

Comment: @vadian If I set coordinate to optional, I get the following error: "Non-'@objc' property 'coordinate' does not satisfy requirement of '@objc' protocol 'MKAnnotation'"

Comment: Then declare the coordinate as `0.0/0.0` if there is no value: `CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.lat ?? 0.0, longitude: self.lon ?? 0.0)`

Comment: @vadian I found that this resolved the immediate issue, but I was able to pinpoint the root cause. When I decode the JSON file, for some reason there are multiple nil entries at the end of all my valid entries. I'll have to go back and investigate where these nil entries are coming from. Thank you!

Comment: make `var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D` a computed property

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61488292/custom-class-conformance-to-mkannotation-and-codable/61491122#61491122 for example.