# Custom class conformance to MKAnnotation and Codable

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotation, codable, cllocationcoordinate2d

I'm working on a group project application in Swift for iOS that allows users to save Location(s) as part of a Tour using Firebase. Our `User` object is a custom class that we hope to conform to `Codable` for use with the CodableFirebase CocoaPod. However, the issue arises when trying to conform the `Location` object to `Codable` because it also has to conform to `MKAnnotation`... and we are all fairly new to this. It's possible that some solutions have gone over my head... entirely possible.

This is our `Location` object:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import CodableFirebase

class Location: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var locationName: String?
    var locationDescription: String?
    var locationImage: UIImage?

    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, locationName: String, locationDescription: String, locationImage: UIImage) {

        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.locationName = locationName
        self.locationDescription = locationDescription
        self.locationImage = locationImage

    }
}
```

And this is our `User` model object:

```
import UIKit
import CloudKit

class User {

    //MARK: - Editable Public Profile Info
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var userStateOfOrigin: States
    var userImage: UIImage?
    var aboutMe: String
    var languages: [Language]

    //MARK: - Editable Personal Info (Includes all Public Profile info)
    var email: String?
    var phoneNumber: String?

    //MARK: - Hidden Variables
    var userId: String
    var userCreatedTours: [Tour]
    var savedLocations: [Location]
    var savedTours: [Tour]
    var bookedTours: [Tour]
    var previouslyExperiencedTours: [Tour]
    var userRating: [Rating]

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String, userStateOfOrigin: States, userImage: UIImage? = nil, aboutMe: String, languages: [Language] = [], email: String?, phoneNumber: String? = "", userId: String, userCreatedTours: [Tour] = [], savedLocations: [Location] = [], savedTours: [Tour] = [], bookedTours: [Tour] = [], previouslyExperiencedTours: [Tour] = [], userRating: [Rating] = []) {

        // editable Public info
        self.firstName =  firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.userStateOfOrigin = userStateOfOrigin
        self.userImage = userImage
        self.aboutMe = aboutMe
        self.languages = languages

        // editable personal info
        self.email = email
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber

        // Hidden Variables
        self.userId = userId
        self.userCreatedTours = userCreatedTours
        self.savedLocations = savedLocations
        self.savedTours = savedTours
        self.bookedTours = bookedTours
        self.previouslyExperiencedTours = previouslyExperiencedTours
        self.userRating = userRating

    }
}
```

We do have a few other custom objects, but I think once this issue is solved, we should be able to easily conform those to `Codable`. Ultimately, it would be great to be able to make these both conform to `Codable` for easy use with Firebase. However, if that's not possible, or the most prudent route, I'm very open to suggestions. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of observations:

1. `MKAnnotation` protocol has `title` and `subtitle` properties (that many annotation views use). I might suggest renaming `locationName` and `locationDescription`, respectively.
2. I’d suggest making these properties `dynamic`, that way if you ever update them, the changes will be updated on their respective annotation views.

   For example, [the documentation for `coordinate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotation/1429524-coordinate) says:

   > Your implementation of this property must be key-value observing (KVO) compliant. For more information on how to implement support for KVO, see [Key-Value Observing Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177i).

   The easy way to do this in Swift is with the `dynamic` keyword.
3. To make this `Codable`, either:

   - the properties must be `Codable`, too; or
   - you will need to manually implement `init(from:)` and `encode(to:)` to do the decoding and encoding, respectively. See [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) for examples.

   Given that neither `CLLocationCoordinate2D` nor `UIImage` conform to `Codable`, I’d lean towards this second option.
4. A very minor point, but I might not use a type name of `Location`, but rather using something with `Annotation` in the name, to make it clear what the object is. It also helps avoid confusion with location objects, e.g. `CLLocation`. I used `CustomAnnotation` below, which isn’t a great name, but hopefully you can come up with a name that makes more sense within your app, but also has `Annotation` within the name.

Thus, pulling this all together you might do something like:

```
class CustomAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation, Codable {
    dynamic var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    dynamic var title: String?
    dynamic var subtitle: String?
    dynamic var image: UIImage?

    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String?, subtitle: String?, locationImage: UIImage?) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.image = locationImage
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title, subtitle, image, latitude, longitude
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        title = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .title)
        subtitle = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .subtitle)

        let latitude = try values.decode(CLLocationDegrees.self, forKey: .latitude)
        let longitude = try values.decode(CLLocationDegrees.self, forKey: .longitude)
        coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

        let data = try values.decodeIfPresent(Data.self, forKey: .image)
        image = data.flatMap { UIImage(data: $0) }
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        try container.encodeIfPresent(title, forKey: .title)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(subtitle, forKey: .subtitle)
        try container.encode(coordinate.latitude, forKey: .latitude)
        try container.encode(coordinate.longitude, forKey: .longitude)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(image?.pngData(), forKey: .image)
    }
}
```